# Is this function continuous? If not, find the Lebesgue measure of the subset on which it is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n(x^k-x^{2k}), x \in E=[0,1], f(x) = lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x), x \in E$. Is $f(x)$ continuous on $E$?

I'm assuming the answer is no, but I really don't see it.  This question is from an old exam that doesn't have answers posted and I can't seem to find anything similar online.

I can't tell if each $f_n$ is continuous.  They are all finite sums of continuous functions, so I would think that each $f_n$ would be continuous.  Then the pointwise limit of a seq of uniformly continuous functions is continuous but I'm guessing we don't have uniform continuity here.  To start this I said suppose it is uniformly continuous then $\exists N$ such that $\forall \epsilon, \forall n,m > N$, WLOG n>m, $|f_n - f_m | < \epsilon$, but that means $\sum_{k=n}^m(x^k(1-x^k)) < \epsilon \forall x \in [0,1]$, but I can't reach a contradiction. Can someone please explain this to me?

Edit: After posting this I read part b of the question, which is "does $f_n$ converge to $f$ uniformly in $E$"

Comment: It is not uniformly convergent, note that $\|f_n-f_{n-1}\|\geq 1/4$, since $(f_{n}-f_{n-1})(\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}})=1/4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually compute the limit of $f_n$ by hand, it is the difference of two geometric series. You get $\lim f_n(x)=x/(1-x^2)$ if $x\neq 1$ and $\lim f_n(1)=0$ . So $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$. And therefore $f_n$ do not converge uniformly, otherwise $f$ would be continuous(uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous).

Answer (score 0):

$f_n(x)=\frac{1-x^{n}}{1−x}- \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1−x^2};\ x\neq1$, which converges to $\frac{1}{1−x}- \frac{1}{1−x^2}\neq 0$ on $[0,\epsilon]$ for every $0\le \epsilon<1.$ On the other hand, $f_n(1)=0$ and as $f(x)$ does not approach a finite limit as $x\to 1$, so $f$ is not continuous at $x=1$ and therefore, the $f_n$ can not converge uniformly on $[0,1].$

Comment: how did you get that $f_n(x)$ equals that?

Comment: It's the formula for a geometric series.